# Will multiple regression work in my small sample?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, small-sample

I have a sample of size n=14, with 1 dependent and 6 independent variables (iv). r=0.85 with the first iv, others are 0.4 or less. Will multiple regression work? If not, why not?

All I have is a correlation matrix that doesn't show p values.
There is a substantial variation in the data for one iv (national GDP).

My concern is that a regression will be inherently unstable due the small sample size and large variation in data values.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by work. Most software these days is quite forgiving but one would suspect any coefficient estimates would by imprecise.

Comment: Possible answers depend on the goal and context of your analysis. Please elaborate on what you mean by "unstable" or "work", e.g. by updating your post.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It was a poor choice of words on my part.

Comment: The aim is to use a regression model to determine the size of a particular market for each country based on known data for 14 countries for which market size is known. Six variables have been included in the model to determine market size. The correlations for the six with the market size in the 14 countries is stated above. I am not doing the analysis myself. I'm simply attempting to determine if such a model would be robust/credible.